# re-registration of an existing user

Tags: security, registration

I've been working on some Tryhackme labs, more specifically on the OWASP Top 10.
I've come across a vulnerability (re-registration)i don't really understand how it works

[image]

Can someone explain to me how it works (supposed to be a developer mistake)

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess without seeing the full context of the question, but a common logic failure would be this pseudo-code:

```
user_name = form_value ( "username" )
if ( exists_in_database( user_name ) )
{
    error( "This user already exists" )
}
else
{
    register_new_user( user_name )
}

function register_new_user( user_name )
{
    cleaned_user_name = trim_whitespace( user_name )
    add_user_to_database( cleaned_user_name )
}
```

The trimming of whitespace happens AFTER checking for an existing user, so the check was not valid and does not catch that "admin" exists.

One way this might have happened is if someone noticed problems with the register_new_user function allowing names like "Alice " then later Alice can't log in because the name she types is just "Alice".  The bug fix added is to trim the user name, but it is added in the wrong location.  It seems to work because now no users with spaces are being created.